# Conditionally adding tables to the dom using coffescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, html-table

I have some json that contains an array of event objects, each event has a date and a name.
In coffeescript I want to loop through the json, check if each object already has a table on the page with an id the same as the event date; if it does then add the event name to the table with the same event date, and if not create a new table with the event date as id and add the name to the table.

I'm not sure why I can't get it to work, even disregarding adding the event names as table data, my code creates a table for every event, rather than only one per date.

```
for event,i in events
  date = event["date"]
  if $("table ##{date.replace(/\s+/g, '')}").length is 0
  table = "<table id='#{date.replace(/\s+/g, '')}'>
    <thead><tr><th>#{date}</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody></tbody></table>"
    $('#matches').append table
```

I loop through the events array, check if there is a table with an id the same as the date of the current item, and if not create the table and add it to the page, but this adds a table for every item!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The space in your selector will look for an ID that is descendent from the element, not the element itself.

Without seeing html and array sample is hard to help further but selector is defintiely problematic if you have `<table id="someval">` and want to check that id .

Since ID's in page must be unique by defintion, it is actually more efficient just to use the ID in selector only. An ID search is fastest DOM search.

Also I don't read `coffee` well. Not sure what the double `##` is. Output should only be a single`#` and there shouldn't be any `{}` in output for selector

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple !!  The first # is to create the id the second #{} is for string interpolation.

Comment: ok..I figured as much but added those comments just for certainty. Be helpful to post browser source in future...for most is easier to read ( and test) and you can always reverse engineer edits back into coffee